# Kiel diri la francan "collectivités d'outre-mer" en Esperanto

Tags: translation

En Vikipedio oni foje uzas la vorton "transmara kolektivo", foje "kolektivumo". Sed "kolektivumo" ne estas en vortaroj.

Respondantoj ŝajne kreas propran ideon pri traduko, sed mi volas scii, kio estas la vorto vere uzata en Francio aŭ internacie por priparoli tion ĉi. Alie, variaj personoj alternative uzus vortojn kiel "kolektivo", "kolektivumo", "komunumo", "teritorio", "regiono", "dividaĵo", ktp.

Comment: Bonvolu klarigi, kion signifas ‘collectivités d'outre-mer’? Kio estas la kunteksto?

Comment: Estas artikoloj en [franc-lingva Vikivortaro](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/collectivit%C3%A9_d%E2%80%99outre-mer) kaj [franc-lingva Vikipedio](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectivit%C3%A9_d%27outre-mer). Ĉu temas pri tiu afero?

Comment: Jes temas pri tiu afero. Mi ne scias, tamen, ĉu vikia fonto estas fidinda.

Answer (score 3):

Por internacia legantaro, pli klara estus "transmaraj teritorioj", ĉar fakte tiaj estas "collectivités d'outre-mer" laŭ Vikipedio.

Comment: Mi samopinias, ke klariga termino "transmaraj teritorioj" estas plej bona. Se la franca esprimo devenas el la franca leĝado aŭ simila fonto, oni povas uzi la klarigan terminon kiel priskribon pri la leĝa termino. Ekz. "La transmaraj teritorioj de Francio konstigas komunumon, kiu nomas transmara komunumo kaj kiun oni submetis al komuna leĝado."

Comment: Tiu traduko bonas ... Tre bonas fakte. La komento de @JuhaMetsäkallas estas ankaŭ tute trafa. Mi ne scius kiun respondon elekti, dependas de kiel multe vi volas respekti la francan "senton". Sed tiu ĉi aspektas pli klare, internaciece klare. Mi voĉdonas por tiu ĉi.

Answer (score 1):

Mi tradukus tion per

`transmara komunumo`

pro tio ke en la esperanta [komunumo](https://vortaro.net/#komunumo_kdc) ankaŭ rilatas administran regionon, kiu povas esti ĉu malgranda (ĉirkaŭ urbo) ĉu pli granda (kuniĝo de ŝtatoj).

Tiuj du signifoj bone priskribas kaj la geografian kaj la administran trajtojn de tiuj insularoj.